# How can I move back and forth within an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of articles that I want to display. I want to be able to click on a next-arrow to move to the next article, or a previous-arrow to move to the previous article. When I get to the last item in the array, I want to hide the next arrow and vice versa for the first item.

```
$(function () {

    var i = 0


    $(multibubbles[i]).appendTo('#page');
    $(multibubbles[i]).children('#next-arrow').show();

        $(multibubbles[i]).children('#next-arrow').click(function (e) {
            $(multibubbles[i]).hide();
            i++;
            $(multibubbles[i]).appendTo('#page');
            if (i == multibubbles.length - 1) {
                $(multibubbles[i]).children('#next-arrow').hide();
            }
            else {
                $(multibubbles[i]).children('#next-arrow').show();
            }
            $(multibubbles[i]).children('#prev-arrow').show();
        })

        $(multibubbles[i]).children('#prev-arrow').click(function (e) {
            $(multibubbles[i]).hide();
            i--
            $(multibubbles[i]).appendTo('#page');
            if (i == 0) {
                $(multibubbles[i]).children('#prev-arrow').hide();
            }
            else {
                $(multibubbles[i]).children('#prev-arrow').show();
            }
            $(multibubbles[i]).children('#next-arrow').show();
        })
})
```

When I click the arrow the first time it goes to the next article fine, but if I click it again it does nothing because I can't get it to exit the first click function. I tried using 'return' but that didn't work either. Please help me.

Comment: where do you reset your click binders? they're not re-attached just because `i` changes, since the function is only executed once. somewhere in your code you need to loop back around to binding listeners to the new objects

Comment: Please use semicolons!

Comment: When an element is moved around in the DOM all events are unbound from that element. To preserve events you could use jQuery `clone(true, true)` in combination with the append. Similar to `var $clone = $(element).clone(true, true); $(element).remove(); $clone.appendTo('targetElement')`; No knowing your exact DOM mark-up I wouldn't be able to say if it applies in your case or not. Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) to show the issue?

Comment: There is no DOM markup for this, other than '#page,' which is what I am appending the array to. I have a searchbox for a user to type in an article tag and ajax returns an array of articles that have that tag.

Comment: @jbr3zy Yeah that's what I need to figure out to do. How do I reset the click while retaining the value of i?

Comment: @Nubby, you can wrap the `.click()` lines in a function called `reset`, and then call `reset()` at the end of each listener's handler (and at the very beginning, of course)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you only have one "next page" element and one "previous page" element. In that case, there's not a need for using an array "multibubbles" for that. I'm assuming "multibubbles" can be set up as an array of string values. Since your "next arrow" elements likely starts out visible, there's no need to use "show()". If you wish to make it invisible, just change the css display for the id '#next-arrow'. Also, set '#prev-arrow' to be initially hidden in css.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    multibubbles[1] = 'blah blah';
    multibubbles[2] = 'blah blah';
    ...

    var numarticles = multibubbles.length;
    var i=0;
    $('#next-arrow').click(function () {
        i++;
        if (i == (numarticles-1)) {
            $('multibubbles[i]').show();
            $('#next-arrow').hide();
            i = numarticles-1;
        }
        $('#prev-arrow').show();
    });

    $('#prev-arrow').click(function () {
        i--;
        if (i == 0) {
            $(multibubbles[i]).show();
            $(#prev-arrow).hide();
            i=0;
        }
        $('#next-arrow').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: There isn't a fixed amount of articles. The user searches a tag and my database returns all the articles that have that tag. This is why I feel like I need to put them into arrays. The arrows that should move back and forth within the array are appended to each article.